# Google Cloud, Gnome via SSH

Tags: ssh, gnome, x-server, google-cloud

I'm running CentOS7 via Google Compute and installed Gnome successfully via `yum` and trying to start the console, but returns this error:

```
xauth:  file /home/sublyime/.serverauth.7851 does not exist

(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
        Perhaps you do not have console ownership?
(EE) 
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Network is unreachable
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Ideas?